# Looking for meadows in December

Tags: usa, recommendations

I am looking for a December time vacation destination in USA. A meadow type terrain. Somehow flat vast lush and green area and if possible has wild flowers and rivers around that'd be ideal. Does anyone have a suggestion or recommendation of where should I look at?

Do lush green meadows, preferably with blooming wild flowers and running water, exist in the US anywhere in December for a hiking or camping trip, and if so where? We are willing to travel.

Comment: That's a tall order. Florida, maybe? Puerto Rico?